# UriComponentsBuilder construct a URI from existing URI without hardcoding URI variables

Tags: java, spring, urlencode, query-string

I'm receiving a redirect URI as a String which is something like this - `http://example.com/#/login`.

It can also be some arbitrary URI String like this -

`http://example.com/#/login?param1=hi` or this - `http://example.com`

and I have to take that URI as is and add some query parameters to it.

So I'm constructing the URI like so.

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri("http://example.com/#/login")
                    .queryParam("param1", "hi")
                    .build();
```

But when I build, the output looks like this:

`http://example.com?param1=hi#/login`

instead of the expected output which is this:

`http://example.com/#/login?param1=hi`

How can I make sure the redirect URI I receive is parsed correctly and query parameters added at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Everything after the hash is called the "fragment".
The URI syntax (defined in [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3)) puts the query parameters before the fragment.

```
URI = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

So the `UriComponentsBuilder` is doing the correct thing according to the spec.

It looks like your system has its own method of using the fragment to provide *pseudo* query parameters within the fragment. Unfortunately, if you want to do this, you are going to have to manage (and encode) such "parameters" yourself and then set the fragment appropriately.

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri("http://example.com/")
                .fragment("/login?param1=hi")
                .build();
```

You might be able to do it by using a *second* UriComponentsBuilder to manage the path and parameters that you want to end up in the fragment. Then `build()` that one and extract the parts you want and put them in the fragment.

```
UriComponents fragmentUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri("http://unused/")
                .path("/login")
                .queryParam("param1", "hi")
                .build();

UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri("http://example.com/")
                .fragment(fragmentUri.getPath() + "?" + fragmentUri.getQuery())
                .build();
```

(Untested code, but hopefully gives you the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com").path("#/login");
uriBuilder.queryParam("email", emailReciepient);
uriBuilder.queryParam("key", jobKey).build().toString();
```

this is the way to do it, as path will be read as it is,